# Finding vector data for UK railway lines?

Tags: data, united-kingdom, railroad

Can someone point me in the direction as to where I can obtain vector layers for the following UK railway lines:

DLR,
GREAT ANGLIA,
TfL RAIL,
OVERGROUND,
C2C,
SOUTH EASTERN

Comment: It looks like someone else is looking for similar data at [opendata.se]: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/rail-track-data-of-the-uk-as-arcs-lines-consisting-of-lat-long-points

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure these sources have exactly what you are looking for, but they may be good sources:

- [Ordnance Survey Open Data website](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html).
- [TFL Open Data API](https://tfl.gov.uk/info-for/open-data-users/data-feeds?intcmp=29422#on-this-page-1) includes "Routes and lines (topology and geographical)"
- [GTFS Data Exchange](http://www.gtfs-data-exchange.com/agencies) has information on a large number of rail agencies.

Comment: If you find the files you are looking for, please update your post for anyone in the future looking for the same files.

Comment: certainly, i found what I was looking for on the Geofabrik website: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/england.html

Answer (score 3):

Check [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/).

They might have what you're looking for and you can use [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/), [Planet OSM](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/), [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) to download shapefiles or whatever format you need.

Answer (score 2):

A search on [data.gov.uk](http://data.gov.uk) for rail returns several datasets that you might find useful.

For example **Network Rail - railway network Inspire data**

There's a [WFS](http://inspire.misoportal.com/geoserver/transport_direct_railnetwork/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&) and a [WMS](http://inspire.misoportal.com/geoserver/transport_direct_railnetwork/wfs?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&) for the rail network and for stations

Here's a preview

[image: UK rail network and stations]

Comment: WFS and WMS links no longer work :(

Comment: @Matt well as the metadata states `This data contains points detailing the location of each Station in the UK and the centre line of the railway track for the network that is managed by Network Rail. It is one of the UK data sets within the Inspire Transport Theme. It is expected the data set from Network Rail will be updated on a six monthly basis.`  it is an INSPIRE dataset, then there should be  a service somewhere.  It would be worth contacting network rail to see if this is a glitch or if the service has moved.